# Ansible handler for resting password to change the password on first login

Tags: ansible, ansible-handlers

Hello working on a ansible script to create a ssh user and on the first login to be forced to changed the password.
The idea is ok, but seems like handler is not ok for the ansible 2.7.7 with python version 3.7.3.
Here is the actual script and actual syntax

```
- name: Add {{ user }} user
  user:
    name: "{{ user }}"
    state: present
    groups: "rebel"
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: $1$Somesdfs$AVJ/Zl.pfCejORtGpE4p..
    update_password: on_create
  notify: force change password


handlers:
  - name: force change password
    command: "chage -d 0 {{ user }}"
    when: user.changed
```

Here is the error

> fatal: [192.168.12.147]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Syntax Error while
>   loading YAML.\n  did not find expected '-' indicator\n\nThe error
>   appears to have been in
>   '/home/klevin/Rebel/ansible-user-sync/edit_users/internal_add_users.yml':
>   line 57, column 1, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the
>   exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to
>   be:\n\n\nhandlers:\n^ here\n"}

Line 57 is where the handler line start

Comment: This is clearly a syntax error. Can you post complete yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be issue with the yam file you posted, with the syntax, specifically with spaces and "-" symbol.

I updated the yaml, since complete yaml is not provided, as below, and it ran successfully without any syntax errors.

```
- name: "Test"
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Add {{ user }} user
      user:
        name: "{{ user }}"
        state: present
        groups: "rebel"
        shell: /bin/bash
        password: $1$Somesdfs$AVJ/Zl.pfCejORtGpE4p..
        update_password: on_create
      notify: force change password
  handlers:
    - name: force change password
      command: "chage -d 0 {{ user }}"
      when: user.changed
```

Make sure "hosts", "tasks" and "handlers" are having correct format/spacing along with line below them for "- name:"